# what are the vxworks system tasks tStkPoll and tStack?

Tags: task, vxworks

For test purposes i put snippet of code in a task switch hook in order to collect information about the task cpu usage. In doing so i found some system tasks i was unfamiliar with. *Can anyone tell me what the responsibilities are of the tStack and tStkPoll tasks?* I am running VxWorks Cert 6.6 with Cert Network Stack.

I ran this code on an application running vxworks 5.5 only and those system task were not present; so i'm guessing they are related to the Cert Network Stack, but i'd like to know for sure (i couldn't find anything in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `i` command on the VxWorks shell. This command will give you (together with various other things) the current program counter (PC) of all tasks of the system.

By doing this several times you will get some addresses the tasks `tStack` and `tStkPoll` are executing code of. By passing one of those addresses to `lkupAddr` you will get the name of the symbols close to that address.

Maybe this gives a hint on what the tasks are doing...